# how to separate all data from the html response inside JSON response in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios6, html-parsing, xcode4.5

I m working on a chat application  and i m getting a HTML response inside JSON response from server as chat History. Below is the response.

```
{ "status": "valid","chats": [{ "ces": "d5c15cf47d8e8684cfbebbc606f7d901", "fav":"0", "text": "<div class='ca'><i>sometext</i></div><><div class='ca'><b>prasad</b> has joined the chat.</div><><cid_1358766005><div class='co'><span class='notranslate'><b>prasad<timestamp_1358766041_co>:</b></span> hi</div></cid_1358766005><><div class='cl'><disconnected><d6>The party has left or disconnected.  Chat session has ended.</div><>" } ] }
```

I want to separate them and Show in a table view.

I just tried to strip the HTML tag with the following category :

```
-(NSString *) stringByStrippingHTML {
    NSRange r;
    NSString *s = [self copy] ;
    while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
        s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
    return s;
}
```

But i m not getting all the data. I m never getting the timestamp. Please any one guide me How to get all the data.Thanks for your time.

Comment: First use a JSON parser to make the data accessible.  Extract the HTML.  Use an XML parser on the HTML.  One step at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSXMLParser. It's Apple's class for parsing XML documents.

Or else  there are lot of open source libraries like TinyXML,Seismic XML etc for parsing XML documents.

Hope it Helps !!!

Comment: Actually data is Coming as JSON Response. And inside the Json response the above chat message coming like {"chats":"htmldata"}

Comment: In either case you have to use some parsing mechanism to extract the data. If you ahve to parse JSOn use NSJSONSerialization class from Apple.

Comment: Yes i m Using the same. But before using `NSJSONSerialization` i have to remove the `HTML` tags and there is the problem.

Comment: so use NSXMLParser or TinyXML to extract the contents from the tags & then apply NSJSONSerialization.